# Indy IdTCPClient + Firemonkey (iOS): OnConnect fires before a connection is established?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy10

I'm trying to establish a simple TCP connection from the FireMonkey iOS App using Indy IdTCPClient. In the case of use in FireMonkey fires *OnConnect* immediately after *.Connect* before successfully connection to server is established. So it's not possible to handle possibly occurring connection exceptions.

Am I the only one with this problem or am I doing something wrong? I use XE7.

Comment: Indy has blocking style communications, you don't have to use events at all?

Comment: Perhaps give the OnConnected event a try.

Answer (score 0):

The `OnConnected` event is triggered immediately after the socket is physically connected to the server, before any data is exchanged, and before `Connect()` exits.  If an error occurs, an exception is raised.  Simply wrap `Connect()` with a `try/except` block to catch connection errors, eg:

```
try
  Client.Connect;
except
  // handle connection error
end;
```

Since Indy operations are blocking, any code you want to use in `OnConnected` can alternatively be done after `Connect()` exits, eg:

```
//Client.OnConnected := ClientConnected;
try
  Client.Connect;
except
  // handle connection error
end;

...

procedure TMyForm.ClientConnected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // connection successful, do something
end;
```

```
try
  Client.Connect;
except
  // handle connection error
  raise;
end;
// connection successful, do something
```

Comment: This is the case by a VCL application. But not by a FireMonkey application. The code in Your example is exactly what I do too. That's the problem. I give a purposely wrong host and port. With these host/port the socket can not be physically connected, but OnConnected still fires immediately after Connect() and tries to send data to server. No connection error, nothing.

Comment: Indy operates the same way on all platforms, using the same BSD-compatible socket API on all platforms. Trust me, I am the primary developer of Indy, so I know that `Connect()` does not operate the way you describe. It is physically impossible normal conditions. The **only** way `OnConnected` can fire is if the OS does not report an error when the underlying socket API `connect()` function is called. If it succeeds, a connection has been established. Also don't forget that a non-IP `Host` must be resolved to an IP first, so that is another check `Connect()` can fail for an invalid `Host`.

Comment: What you describe would only be possible if Delphi's exception handling is broken on iOS, and that is highly unlikely.

Comment: Remy, I know that You are a Indy developer and I trust You 100%. And I'm so thankful for Your valuable time that You took to help with my problem. But it happens exactly what I have described. I just installed iOS Simulator 7.1 (8.1 not working yet) and the code runs perfectly in sumulator. This problem only affects the device.

Comment: Then you are going to have to debug your app on the device and see where the failure point actually is. Indy is expecting iOS to report an error, and if so then will raise an exception. If that is not happening, then either iOS is broken, or Delphi is broken. Indy uses the same socket code (in fact, the same `TIdStack`-derived class) for all of FireMonkey's platforms other than Windows. Worse case, write some code that makes the same socket API function calls and exception raising calls that Indy uses, and see which one is misbehaving.